# Add random function to dynamically created buttons

Tags: javascript, html, arrays, button, onclick

So I've created some buttons dynamically using a for loop nothing fancy , however to each button I need to assign a random function from an array of functions and a random style. How would one go about that ?

Also how do i run the buttons because

```
button.addEventListener ("click", actions[i]());
```

Still just executes the function not on the button

My code

```
let i = 1;
let body = document.getElementsByTagName("body")[0];
//Functions
let actions = [add,clear,flow]
//styles color of btn ?
let styles = ["blue","red"]

for (i; i <= 20; i++) {
  let button = document.createElement("button");
  button.innerHTML = 'Button '+i;
  body.appendChild(button);
  //heres where i'm lost
  button.addEventListener ("click", function() {
    alert(this.innerHTML);
  });
}
```

Comment: you need to pass the function without the (), if you pass with the () it implies the result of the funciton, while if you pass without it means you are passing the function object

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
button.addEventListener ("click", actions[i]());
```

Attempts to call the function at the time that you are assigning it because of the parenthesis at the end. When setting up event handlers, you just pass a reference to the function (so no parenthesis).

You'll need to get random numbers based on the length of the arrays and then pass those random numbers into their respective arrays to get a value from it.

See comments inline below.

```js
// There is only one body, no need to try to find all of them
let body = document.body;

//Functions
function add(){
  console.log("add");
}

function clear(){
  console.log("clear");
}

function flow(){
  console.log("flow");
}

let functions = [add,clear,flow];

// Use the names of predefined classes
let classes = ["blue","red", "green", "yellow", "orange"];

// You should get used to starting to count from 0 because
// that's the first index in JavaScript arrays.
for (let i = 0; i < 20; i++) {
  let button = document.createElement("button");
  // Don't use .innerHTML when you aren't working with HTML
  button.textContent = 'Button '+ (i + 1);
  
  // Get a random number that maps to one of the indexes in the
  // classes array and then get that class out of the array and
  // add it to the element
  button.classList.add(classes[Math.floor(Math.random() * classes.length)]);
  
  body.appendChild(button);
  
  //heres where i'm lost
  // Get a random number that maps to one of the indexes in the 
  // functions array and pick that function to assign
  
  // Get the random number that will be the array index:
  let index = [Math.floor(Math.random() * functions.length)];
  
  // Check to see if that index points to the clear function
  if(functions[index] === clear){
    // If so, add the CSS class that hides it.
    button.classList.add("hidden");
  }
  button.addEventListener ("click", functions[index]);
}
```

```css
.blue { background-color:skyblue; }
.red { background-color:red; }
.green { background-color:green; }
.yellow { background-color: yellow; }
.orange { background-color: orange; }

.hidden { display:none; }
```

Comment: YOU ARE A SAINT!!!! THANKS ALOT!!! One more question only if you've got the time though, for the button that has the clear function how would I target it and remove that specific button's visibility to none ?

Comment: @MindQ You would check to see what function was selected as the random one before assigning it and it it is clear, then apply a CSS class that sets the visibility to none. I'll update the answer to show this.

Comment: If i could infinite upvote you I would THANKS A MILLION